# How to stop images from being wrapped in <p> tags?

Tags: images, content

I'm trying to stop the WordPress from automatically wrapping `<img>`s with `<p>` tags. I've tried this recommended snippet in my `functions.php`:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){ // Remove p tags from around images
     return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);

}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

This doesn't works if an image is the **first** element in a post or page. When an image comes before any text, the image gets wrapped with `<p>` tags once again. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are your images wrapped with `<p>` in the first place? Are you talking about the `<p>` that wraps the whole post? I don't get any special `<p>` tags for each image..

Comment: @N00b I don't want them to be wrapped with `<p>`, it's something that Wordpress tends to do automatically (part of wpautop I believe). I'm trying to eliminate that behaviour for images.

Comment: The point is that WordPress doesn't do that by itself. Either your theme or some other plugin is causing it.  What does the text in your editor look like before you publish the post?

Comment: @BillK not true. if you add image to the wysiwyg editor, images get wrapped inside p tags. true story.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *remove* `<p>` from entire content (not only from the images), this can help you

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_226099_remove_p' );
function wpse_226099_remove_p( $content ) {
    global $post;
    return $post->post_content;
}
```

or maybe with this-

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop')
```

Comment: remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop') did the trick for me, other methods don't work.

Answer (score 1):

this is a function, that unwraps images from p tags inside the_content

```
/**
 * WP: Unwrap images from <p> tag
 * @param $content
 * @return mixed
 */
function so226099_filter_p_tags_on_images( $content ) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>\\s*?(<a .*?><img.*?><\\/a>|<img.*?>)?\\s*<\\/p>/s', '\1', $content);

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'so226099_filter_p_tags_on_images');
```